# How to get core shipping methods in Commerce 2? How to save an order?

Tags: plugin-development, migration, plugin-craftcommerce2

Is there an equivalent function to `commerce_shippingMethods->getAllCoreShippingMethods()` in Commerce 2?

I can only find `Commerce::getInstance()->getShippingMethods()->getAllShippingMethods();`

I also cant find an equivalent to `craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order)` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`Commerce::getInstance()->getShippingMethods()->getAllShippingMethods();` would be the functional equivilant of Commerce 1's`commerce_shippingMethods->getAllCoreShippingMethods()` since it returns the the shipping methods defined in the database.

`Commerce::getInstance()->getShippingMethods()->getAvailableShippingMethods();` will return the shipping methods in the database as well as any 3rd party defined shipping methods.